# Unable to get proper output of if-else loop

Tags: shell, putty

When i am using multiple if-else i am still getting some syntax error. please help

```
stats=$(rpm -qa | grep MySQL)
set -f  # turn off globbing, so as not to expand wildcards
arr=($(echo "$stats" | sed 's/,/ /g'))
if [[ "${arr[0]}" == "MySQL-server-5.6.11-2.rhel5" ]] && [[ "${arr[1]}" == "MySQL-client-5.6.5_m8-1.rhel5" ]]; then
        rpm -e MySQL-server-5.6.11-2.rhel5
        rpm -e MySQL-client-5.6.5_m8-1.rhel5
        echo "MySQL Successfully Removed";
elif [ "${arr[0]}" == "MySQL-server-5.6.11-2.rhel5" ]; then
         rpm -e MySQL-server-5.6.11-2.rhel5

elif [ "${arr[1]}" == "MySQL-client-5.6.5_m8-1.rhel5" ]; then
         rpm -e "MySQL-client-5.6.5_m8-1.rhel5
else
        echo "Done"

fi
```

Comment: Since when do we put the arguments to a command directly next to the command without any whitespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an space in the 2nd condition:

```
[["${arr[1]}" == "MySQL-client-5.6.5_m8-1.rhel5"]]
  ^                                            ^
   \                                          /
    - here                              here -
```

so it is

```
[[ "${arr[1]}" == "MySQL-client-5.6.5_m8-1.rhel5" ]]
```